# PI 3 SSH No route to host

Tags: pi-3, ssh

I am following this tutorial :

http://www.widriksson.com/raspberry-pi-hadoop-cluster/

I am using Raspberry Pi 3. When I tried to test SSH connection same like the tutorial, I am getting:

```
ssh: connect to host hadoopmaster port 22: No route to host
```

Also I don't know if the file /etc/network/interfaces is the right file to put my network configuration :

```
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.0.110
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway: 192.168.0.1
```

because It is empty and when I put the IPs in it, I can't connect to wifi anymore.

I tried also to put the static IP cofiguration inside /etc/dhcpcd.conf and I am getting the same above error when I try to open ssh connection.

I also added a host name and IP to  /etc/hosts , which is not mentioned in the tutorial, but nothing worked.

[image]

Comment: You are using a 3 year old tutorial, written before the Pi3 existed, and there have been 2 OS upgrades since!

Comment: Yeah, I know. This is the best tutorial I could found. 
So, do you know a solution for this?

Comment: The top answer [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/37920/how-do-i-set-up-networking-wifi-static-ip-address/37921#37921) should help

Comment: Maybe it's just a confusion a confusion between `hadoopmaster` and  `hadoopMaster`?

Comment: First question:  Can you `sudo ping` to the target address?  It is quite possible that there is indeed no route to the host.

Answer (score 1):

There shouldn't be a colon `:` after gateway. Apart from that, you might be bothered by case sensitivity. You're connecting to hadoopmaster, but specified hadoopMaster.

Answer (score 0):

Try to SSH locally from the same machine to verify that whether the ssh service is running.

Looks like you are trying to communicate over wifi and you are setting your network configuration for ethernet.

Also as @88weighed pointed out the `:` and case sensitivity.

Hope that helps